# Syntax error in query generated from PowerBI to MariaDB

Tags: powerbi, mariadb, syntax-error, powerbi-desktop, mariadb-10.6

I have the following problem when trying what should be a very basic data manipulation on PowerBI Desktop when connected to MariaDB 10.6.12

In my model, I import some tables, which are then manipulated to combine some ID columns (which form a composite key on the database) to a single field in the Power Query editor, and this merging happens correctly.

However, when I click "Apply & Close" and PowerBI tries to update the data model, it gives me this error:

[image: PowerBI query syntax error]

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as LONG VARCHAR), ?)}, cast(cast(id_categoria as VARCHAR) as LONG VARCHA...' at line 10

By some Google-Fu, I found this [MariaDB ODBC connector bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/ODBC-312), which in turn links to an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-powerbi/issues/11) for the specific MariaDB PowerBI Connector.

As of now, I have updated the ODBC connector to the latest versione 3.1.17, and I also tried to use the custom PowerBI Connector version 1.1.3, which I thought would resolve the issue, however it is still present.

One thing I notice is that the original report seems about VARCHAR fields with length greater than 256, but in my case, I am concatenating integers into a string.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I'll try to rewrite it, sadly that window does not allow copy-paste

Comment: @GeorgRichter copied the error text.